# Using Javascript to scroll to an element automatically when the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html

I made a website that has 2 sections. You have to scroll a bit to come to section 2 so I wanted to make a code which sends you directly to section 2 when you scroll down.

So I made a basic function that works when I use a button to trigger it but I couldn't figure out how can I make this function run when the user scrolls. The function:

```js
function scroll_to_target(){
    document.getElementById("moreinfo").scrollIntoView();
}
```

Basically I need something that when the user scrolls down in the first section of the website it triggers "scroll_to_target()" function which makes the user scroll to "moreinfo" (second section) of the website directly and smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can use jQuery to do that, for the scroll function to hit you could do something like this after importing jQuery to project:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    //call the function here or make any changes
});
```